# jackson objectNode get query

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, jackson

I am using jackson objectNode (in play2.2).  I am able to put a string value in the objectNode like this:

```
objectNode test = Json.newObject();
test.put("check", "stackoverflow");
```

When I try to retrieve the value using a get operation, I can't seem to use equals correctly.  I am guessing its because the String value has additional characters (the inverted commas) - what's the best approach to use equals in this case on the string being stored in the objectNode (this is using dataBind option in jackson).

```
  test.get("check").equals("stackoverflow"); // neither works
  test.get("check").toString().equals("stackoverflow");
```

When I print out the value, I can see the following value i.e. with the inverted commas:

```
"stackoverflow"
```

I would like to avoid using string operations to parse out the value - there must be a better way even if I am using the databinding route.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare objects with appropriate types. The ObjectNode.get() method returns an instance of a JsonNode which cannot be equal to string. While the JsonNode.toString() method returns a quoted JSON representation of the string node, which is not equal to a raw string.

You should rather compare a text context of a JSON node with a input string, or JsonNode objects. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonObjectNode {
    public static class MyObject {
        public String value;

        public MyObject(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyObject object = new MyObject("foo");

        ObjectNode node = mapper.convertValue(object, ObjectNode.class);
        JsonNode stringNode = mapper.convertValue("foo", JsonNode.class);

        System.out.println("ObjectNode.get(...) == 'foo' = " +
                node.get("value").equals("foo"));
        System.out.println("ObjectNode.get(...).toString() == 'foo' = " +
                node.get("value").toString().equals("foo"));

        System.out.println("ObjectNode.get(...).asText == 'foo' = " +
                node.get("value").asText().equals("foo"));
        System.out.println("ObjectNode.get() == JsonNode = " +
                node.get("value").equals(stringNode));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ObjectNode.get(...) == 'foo' = false
ObjectNode.get(...).toString() == 'foo' = false
ObjectNode.get(...).asText == 'foo' = true
ObjectNode.get() == JsonNode = true
```